# extend and figure special treated formula

Tags: c#, formula, brackets

my program tries to extend special formula(see the examples) into explicited one.there are few terms that the furmula has to stand in:
-there isn't a space(" ") in th whole formula
-it formula has just rounded brackets "(,)" and not all of brackets forms"{}[]"
-the formula is contained just letters(a-z,A-Z),digits(also numbers) and rounded brackets.
-for each opening bracket, has to be a suitable closing bracket.
-to formula can't start with brackets.

here are some examples:
*   input: 'abz2(3(a)2(ab))a
    output:'abzaaaababaaaababa

- input: 'a2(A)6(g2(a))'
  output:'aAAgagagagagaga'

and heres the code:

```
        bool ExistBrackets(string st)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
        {
            if (IsBracket(st[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    string AddChainDeleteBracks(int open, int close, string input)
    {
        string to="",from="";
        //get the local chain multipule the number in input[open-1]

        //the number of the times the chain should be multiplied
        for (int i = input[open - 1]; i > 0; i--)
        {
            //the content
            for (int m = open + 1; m < close; m++)
            {
                to = to + input[m];
            }
        }

        //get the chain i want to replace with "to"
        for (int j = open - 1; j <= close; j++)
        {
            from = from + input[j];
        }
        String output = input.Replace(from, to);
        return output;
    }

    private void PopulateStartEnd()
   {
       //assuming that start and end are empty
       int cS=0,cE=0;
       //populate start
       for (int i = 0; i < (textBox1.Text.Length); i++)
       {
           if (textBox1.Text[i] == '(')
           {
               start[cS] = i;
               cS++;
           }
           if (textBox1.Text[i] == ')')
           {
               end[cE] = i;
               cE++;
           }
       }

       }


    private string FigureInput(string st)
    {
        int i,close;
        PopulateStartEnd();
        //get the index in the start array which is populated
        for (i = start.Length - 1; start[i] != 0; i--) ;
        //populate the last letters if there is outside the brackets
        while (!ExistBrackets(st))
        {
            //loop on the latest opening brackets in start array
            for (; i >= 0; i++)
            {
                //find the suitable closing brackets in the end array
                for (close = 0; ((end[close] > start[i]) && (end[close] != null)); close++) ;
                st=AddChainDeleteBracks(i, close, st);
            }
        }

        return st;

    }
```

***the main method is FigureInput***

the error i get:

******* *Exception Text* *********
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at myProject.Formula.PopulateStartEnd() in C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Project\myProject\myProject\Formula.cs:line 156
   at myProject.Formula.FigureInput(String st) in C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Project\myProject\myProject\Formula.cs:line 135
   at myProject.Formula.generateButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Project\myProject\myProject\Formula.cs:line 36

Comment: Did you check the values of the different strings at the point the exception was thrown? Are the string lengths correct? Are the `start` and `end` arrays initialized with the right size?

Comment: start and end are in the same size, but not all the cells are populated. do u mean to the input string?

Comment: Might also be the input string. The exception indicates that you are either trying to access an index that doesn't exist - it could be in `textBox1.Text`, `start` or `end` (check the values of `i`, `cS` and `cE` when the exception occurs and compare to the `Length` of the different arrays).

Comment: i checked it.it was the location of the initializing( do "new int(number)" to end and start. Now it has another problem with **AddChainDeleteBracks** i don't know why, but 'to' and 'from' are empty(="").Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You never check that `close` is less than `end.Length` in the inner most `for` loop in `FigureInput`. Note: strings in C# are not null terminated.

Change the loop to this:

```
for (close = 0; (close < end.Length && (end[close] > start[i])); close++) ;
```

---

I never see you initialize `end` and `start` with an adequate size. Make sure they are big enough or better use a `List<int>` to which you can add the indexes with [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx).

Comment: end and start  are in the half size of the input string.but not all cells in end and start are populated. so how can I ask to get to the last one i populated?